# Store values of a method in array wuthout print, and array comparison issue

Tags: c, arrays

I have a binary tree program. And Im trying to get this output from the program:

```
55, 31, 1 , 49, 39, 47, 64, 65, 98, 97         // (result of print_preorder)
its ok to insertBoth                           // result of comparison
```

But Im getting tihs:

```
 55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97
55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97
55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97
55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97
55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97
55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97
55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97
55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97
55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97
55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97
```

Do you see how to fix this?  How to store in the "arr" array the actual
values in the binary tree? And how to do the comparison? I tried with the methods below
but its not working.

Example working with the issue:

```
        #include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct bin_tree {
    int data;
    struct bin_tree * right, * left;
};
typedef struct bin_tree node;

void insert(node ** tree, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }

}

int  print_preorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        printf("%d ",tree->data);
        int left = print_preorder(tree->left);
        int right = print_preorder(tree->right);
        return  left+right+1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }

}


int main() {
    node *root;
    node *tmp;
    int i, j;
    int arr[] = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1};
    int arrExp[] = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1};

    root = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        insert(&root, arr[i]);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        arr[j] = print_preorder(root);
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == arrExp[i]) {
            printf("test");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also for the comparison I try to use a method:

```
bool check(int actual[], int expected[]) {

    int i = 0;

    while(actual){
        if(actual[i++] != expected[i++])
            return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

And then to use:

```
if(verify(arr,arrExp)){
        printf("test");
    }
    else{
        printf("test no");
    }
```

But I get the same issue.

Also dont works:

```
 bool check(int expected[], node ** tree) {


        int i = 0;

        if(tree == NULL)
            return false;

        for(int i =0; i<sizeof(tree) / sizeof(int); i++){
            if(expected[i++] != (*tree)->data)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The comparison between the array and the pre order result still dont work, it appears always "not same", I should have something wrong but Im not finding where the issue is:

```
int main() {
    node *root = NULL;
    int i, j;
    int arr[] = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    int arrExp[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)] = {0};
    int *ap = arrExp;

    int arrExpPo[] = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1};
    int *apo= arr;

    // insert 10 nodes in the tree
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        insert(&root, arr[i]);

    // print tree
    print_preorder(root);
    puts("\n");

    // compare array with tree (it works)
    outToArray(root, &ap);
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), cmp);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExp[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    // compare array with pre order result (dont works, appears always "not same")
    outToArrayPreOrder(root, &apo);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExpPo[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Are there no `,` in the `55 31 1 49 39 47 64 65 98 97 ` output?  Certainly `printf("%d, ",tree->data);` would produce a comma.  Suspect makefile problem or false/missing code or false output posted.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Its correct now, I was testing like that and forget to change.

Comment: I see no return value in `int  print_preorder`.  Turn up your warnings and pay attention to them.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are all warnings enabled?

Comment: Thanks, Wwith the return Im getting the same result. And it dont show any warning, Im using clion.

Comment: "And it dont show any warning" and "no return value in int print_preorder" implies you still have not "Turn up your warnings".  Time to go.

Comment: If you call a print function 10 times I'd expect 10 things to get printed.  Perhaps you need a function that traverses and doesn't print.  Although, if you're going to call it 10 times exactly the same way you may as well just call it once and assign the value to all 10 slots in your array.  You're going to need to reconsider your logic.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Do you see whats wrong in the method I update? You´r saying something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
void outToArray(node *tree, int **arr){
//Write elements of tree to the array.
    if(tree){
        outToArray(tree->left, arr);
        *(*arr)++ = tree->data;
        outToArray(tree->right, arr);
    }
}

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int x = *(int *)a;
    int y = *(int *)b;
    return x < y ? -1 : x > y;
}

int main(void) {
    node *root = NULL;
    int i, j;
    int arr[] = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    int arrExp[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)] = {0};
    int *ap = arrExp;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        insert(&root, arr[i]);

    print_preorder(root);
    puts("\n");

    outToArray(root, &ap);
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), cmp);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExp[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
void outToArray(node *tree, int **arr){
//pre-order output 
    if(tree){
        *(*arr)++ = tree->data;
        outToArray(tree->left, arr);
        outToArray(tree->right, arr);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    node *root = NULL;
    int i, j;
    int arr[] = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    int arrExp[] = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1};
    int *ap = arr;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        insert(&root, arr[i]);

    print_preorder(root);
    puts("\n");

    outToArray(root, &ap);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExp[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    return 0;
}
```

---

FYI:

{55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1} to BST

```
　　　　55
　　　／　＼
　　31　　　64
　／　＼　　　＼
１　　　49　　　65
　　　／　　　　　＼
　　39　　　　　　　98
　　　＼　　　　　／
　　　　47　　　97
```

pre-order walk in tree
55→31→1→49→39→47→64→65→98→97

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the comparison is not working.It appears that they are always the same. But I think that your solution dont work, because I need to have tow arrays one array with some values to insert on the tree, and then I have the expected array with the expected values. And after insert the nodes on the tree I want to compare if the nodes on the tree are icual and in same order as the expected array. With your solution it seems that the arrays will be always the same so it shows always "same".

Comment: @Jokl `outToArray` is to output the entire contents of the tree to an array. So the array before the tree structure is the same as the output after the output.

Comment: @Jokl Your title seems to want to store the contents of the tree in an array. If you want to test that the contents of the array are all present in the tree you do not need to save it in another array.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. By the way, Im trying to store the result of print_preorder method to compare the result of the method with a expected array "arrExpPrint = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1}" to check if the print result and this array its the same, but for this comparison Im using a for and because this function prints the tree nodes and has 10 nodes it prints 10 times the result. Do you know how to do this comparison without printing the nodes 10 times?

Comment: @Jokl It is easy to change `outToArray` to pre-order output. I add sample to answer. For comparison, there is no problem with my method in for-loop, and you can also use `memcmp`.

Comment: Thanks really for your help and explanations. Im here trying to put this work but is being difficult. I dont understand why the comparison of the tree with the pre order is not working, I update the question with what I have, and it seems fine. Do you see where the issue is?

Comment: @Jokl You get result of `print_preorder` as `55, 31, 1 , 49, 39, 47, 64, 65, 98, 97`. (This is a correct result.) So, It is different from the expected values as `55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1`.

Comment: Sorry, I put arrExpo[55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1] = instead of arrExpo[] = "55, 31, 1, 49, 39, 47, 64, 65, 98, 97". Im testing like this and I get the issue, saying always "not same":

Comment: @Jokl  `55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1` is not result of preoder.

Comment: Thanks for your help really. Im a beginner so its not so easy sometimes. I still have one issue but maybe I ask another question because Im not see why it is happening and I dont know if its ok ask here again and also I can´t vote up in your answer because dont have enough points. Thank you!